# vim - Reopening a deleted buffer not listed on buffer list

Tags: vim

Here is my complete vim configuration files https://bitbucket.org/tristan_ph/dotvim. And my vimrc https://bitbucket.org/tristan_ph/dotvim/src/tip/.vimrc

Here are the steps to re-produce the problem.

1. open a multiple using (Im using FuzzyFinder FufCoverageFile).
   Ex. listings_controller.rb and listings_controller_spec.rb
2. List all open buffer (:ls on ex mode), buffer listed as expected.
   Output: listings_controller.rb and listings_controller_spec.rb
3. Delete the listing_controler.rb buffer using :bd (Before I was using Bclose, I thought this is the cause but when I removed it, the problem persist)
4. Open listing_controller.rb again using FuzzyFinder FufCoverageFile
5. List all open buffer (:ls on ex mode), only listings_controller_spec.rb is on the list.

How do I open the listings_controller.rb that is listed on buffer list (:ls)? Im not sure if this is caused by another plugin.

Comment: Was wondering and am also curious about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `:ls!`  you will also see unlisted buffers.   Here you can see the number of the deleted buffer and can switch to it with `:b#` where # is the buffer number.

Comment: yes you are right, but why is this happening at all? What I want is to open it on a normal buffer list. Is there any explanation on this?

Comment: Or, Im I using the wrong command (:bd) to delete buffer instead I should use another command?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you're trying to do.  Are you closing the buffer just to open another one?  If so, that's not necessary, just `:e newfile` instead.  If you are just trying to open the next file in the list just do `:bn`.